# PHP generate one array index with many values and remove empty array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
[docs] => Array
(
    [indexone] => Array    ( [0] => P008062518   )
    [indextwo] => Array    ( [0] =>              )
    [indexthree] => Array  ( [0] => 0000141334   )
    [indexfour] => Array   ( [0] => P006871638   )
    [indexfive] => Array   ( [0] => 0000910067   )
    [indexsix] => Array    ( [0] =>              )
)
```

I need to end with this one, extracting all values from the given key:

```
[docValues] => Array
(
    [indexone] => Array    ( P008062518, 0000141334, P006871638, 0000910067    )
)
```

I try this loop but i end with the same array structure :

```
foreach($values as $key => $data)
 {
    if(array_key_exists('docs', $data) )
    {
        $filtered = array_filter($data['docs'], function($var) { return !empty($var);});
        $numDocs = array_values($filtered);
        $values[$key]['docValues'] = $numDocs;
    }
}
```

How can it be done ?

Comment: What are you doing here? `Array    ( P008062518<br> 0000141334<br> P006871638<br> 0000910067    )`? did you mean :  `Array    ( P008062518, 0000141334, P006871638,  0000910067    )` because `<br>` makes no sense.... that is html and you are talking about a php array

Comment: Please show some more of your array structure, so we see exactly in which dimension your shown array is.

Comment: @Webeng you are right i will need to add br tag after

Comment: I see you edited your _I need to end with this one_.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get that exact array output:

```
$result['docValues'][key($values['docs'])] =
    array_filter(array_column($values['docs'], 0));
```

- Get the first key to use it as your new key with `key()`
- Get an array of all values in the 0 indexes with `array_column()`
- Remove empty elements using `array_filter()`

Comment: I don't know what you mean.  This gives the exact output given the input from your question.

Answer (score 1):

**Simply do this:**

**Your array**

```
$arr = array("docs" => 
             array(
                 'indexone' => array('P008062518'),
                 'indextwo' => array(''),
                 'indexthree' => array('0000141334'),
                 'indexfour' => array('P006871638'),
                 'indexfive' => array('0000910067'),
                 'indexsix' => array('')
             )
        );
```

**Process:**

```
echo '<pre>';
$index = key($arr["docs"]);

$output['docValues'][$index] = implode('&lt;br/&gt;', array_filter(array_column($arr['docs'], 0)));
print_r($output);
```

**Explanation:**

- **key =** key function Returns the first index.
- **implode =** collapse all the array items with the delimiter of `<br/>`
- **array_filter =** filters the values of an array using a callback
  function.
- **array_column =** returns the values from a single column in the input
  array.

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [docValues] => Array
        (
            [indexone] => P008062518<br/>0000141334<br/>P006871638<br/>0000910067
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you @Fraine! all anwers help me but i use this one.

Answer (score 1):

If your first array is called `$docArray`, then you can do the following:

```
$docValuesArray = array();//declaring the result array
$indexoneArray = array();//declaring the array you will add values
//to in the foreach loop

foreach ($docArray as $value)
{
  $indexoneArray[] = $value[0];//giving each of the values
  //found in $docArray to the $indexoneArray
}

$docValueArray[] = $indexoneArray;//adding the $indexoneArray
//to the $docsValueArray
```

Let me know if that worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick for you:

```
$docs = [
    'indexone' => ['P008062518'],
    'indextwo' => [ ],
    'indexthree' => ['0000141334'],
    'indexfour' => ['P006871638'],
    'indexfive' => ['0000910067'],
    'indexsix' => [ ],
];

$allDocs = array();

foreach($docs as $key => $doc) {
    $docString = implode("<br>",$doc);
    if (empty($docString)) {
        continue;
    }
    $allDocs[] = $docString;
}
$allDocsString = implode("<br>",$allDocs);

echo($allDocsString);
```

---

> P008062518
> 0000141334
> P006871638
> 0000910067

Answer (score 0):

use `array_filter()` function . if you pass array in array_filter then remove all empty and NULL data record

Comment: I erase empty values with this line $filtered = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $data['docs']));